# How to prevent a trigger to be triggered by another trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have two tiggers on `table1`:

1. trigger #1 after update it updates the last modified date column in `table1`
2. trigger #2 after update if `col1` is `0` it creates a log record in `table2`

So the problem is that when I set `col1` to `0` trigger #2 creates the record properly in `table2`, but as trigger #1 modifies the record again, trigger #2 creates another log record in `table2`.

What I want is to prevent trigger #2 to be triggered when trigger #1 modifies any record.

Comment: One way would be to check in trigger #2, whether any column except `last modified` was updated

Comment: Is there a way to check what has been modified?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx look for "Testing for UPDATE or INSERT Actions to Specific Columns"

Comment: check the TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL function

Comment: Another option might to investigate the usage of triggers in the first place. Many (if not most) triggers can be avoided which would eliminate this issue. Aside from auditing their usage really should be minimal at best.

Comment: @SeanLange, I strongly disagree with you. Triggers are important to data integrity as well as auditing and any dev who can't deal with them properly is simply incompetent. You should not be programming around the desires of the incompetent. If you devs aren't competent to deal with triggers, they aren't competent to query the database, period.  So fix that rather than use the application for things that should be handled by the database.

Comment: @HLGEM I disagree that triggers should be used for data integrity under most situations. They can easily be disabled and you can create data that violates the integrity. Most of the time it can be handled with proper constraints. I did not say anything about devs not being able to handle them correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You may in the first trigger issue a disable trigger before the update (under certain circumstances, update the value, then renable the trigger.

In the first trigger:

```
 if (cond1) 
           disable trigger starttrigger2 on table1

    update table1

    enable trigger starttrigger2 on table1
```

Comment: Sry, but had to downvote, the suggestion is simply too dangerous to leave it be..

Comment: Is showing a developer how to disable a trigger so dangerous?

Comment: IMHO yes, it is. In a multi-user, highly transactional environment you can't be sure what the others are doing. Have a first-hand experience in solving problems caused by it.

Comment: Maybe I should have shown wrapping a transaction around the disable/enable. Unless the user uses service broker to do saving state without stepping on other tasks, I don't see a way of doing this.

Comment: I don't see how would the transaction change anything, unless you're in serializable mode, or use the TABLOCKX hint. The point is that other users will do other DML on the table at the same time which _should_ be logged, and it won't happen if the trigger is disabled.

Comment: I meant that the trigger would be guaranteed to be re-enenabled. There would have to be a lot of logic in the second trigger (or maybe making it into one trigger) to avoid what the user is trying to avoid.